# In Pycharm, how to specify unions for type hinting?

Tags: pycharm, type-hinting

Does anyone know how to write a union for the type hinting?

I am doing the following, but it is not being recognised by PyCharm:

```python
def add(a, b)
    # type: (Union[int,float,bool], Union[int,float,bool]) -> Union([int,float,bool])
    return a + b
```

What is the correct way of specifying a type hint for a union?

I am using python 2.7 for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing the following works for me, in Pycharm (version 2016.2.2):

```python
from typing import Union

def test(a, b):
    # type: (Union[int, float, bool], Union[int, float, bool]) -> Union[int, float, bool]
    return a + b
```

Pycharm may be confused because due to the extra parens in your return type, or perhaps because you forgot to import `Union` from the `typing` module.

Comment: I am using python 2.7, I dont have access to the typing module, is a Union only available for python 3?

Comment: @Har - You can install the `typing` module on Python 2.7 by doing `pip install typing`. The `typing` module was added to the standard library in Python 3.5, and is available to install as a 3rd party library on Python 2.7 and Python 3.2 - 3.4.

Answer (score 5):

There are [many ways](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html) to specify unions for type hinting.

In Python 2 and 3 you could use the following:

```python
def add(a, b):
    """
    :type a: int | float | bool
    :type b: int | float | bool
    :rtype: int | float | bool 
    """
    return a + b
```

In Python 3.5 `typing` module was introduced, so you could use one of the following:

```python
from typing import Union

def add(a, b):
    # type: (Union[int, float, bool], Union[int, float, bool]) -> Union[int, float, bool]
    return a + b
```

or

```python
from typing import Union

def add(a, b):
    """
    :type a: Union[int, float, bool]
    :type b: Union[int, float, bool]
    :rtype: Union[int, float, bool]
    """
    return a + b
```

or

```python
from typing import Union


def add(a: Union[int, float, bool], b: Union[int, float, bool]) -> Union[int, float, bool]:
    return a + b
```

Comment: Does that mean that PEP based type hinting is only available in python 3? So the only way is to use docstring type - type hinting for python 2 ?

Comment: mypy works with Python 2: http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python2.html

Comment: @user2235698 and @Har -- that is incorrect; the `typing` module is available to download as a 3rd party library for Python 2.7+, and consequently type hinting is available in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: This works well for typing with `:type`, very useful